# Upload images from App to Imgur

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload images from Tweetbot using the custom image upload service with this PHP script found on Github that uses the client ID given when you register a third-part app on Imgur but nothing seems to work properly. Every time the upload fails. What am I doing wrong? This is the script:

```
<?php
/**
 * Original script source
 * 
 *         http://playground.btolab.com/sandbox/qa/stackexchange/stackoverflow/17269448/index.php
 *         http://playground.btolab.com/sandbox/qa/stackexchange/stackoverflow/17269448/index.php.source
 */
$client_id = "MY_ID";

$image = $_POST['url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => $image ));

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);
$newimgurl = $reply->data->link;

echo $newimgurl;

exit();

?>
```

Comment: Please include more information on the failure -- do you get a response and/or errors?

Comment: Unfortunately what app says me is ' Upload Failed: Failed to upload data. '. Do I have to try this script first on my pc with a form and then with the app?